# Can GitHub Copilot stop auto-suggesting, instead be triggered by a keystroke?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, autosuggest, github-copilot

I find Github Copilot very helpful in some specific situations, but fairly unhelpful in its verbosity in most situations.

By default, it's always on, always suggesting (and frequently getting in my way.) I want it to be less aggressive, disabling the auto-suggestion, but still have it readily available at a keystroke.

**What I've tried already:**

In a [helpful post](https://nira.com/github-copilot/), I see that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> is the default key for triggering Copilot suggestions. Great, that's half of the solution.

In `settings.json`, setting the following seems to disable copilot entirely! It is no longer available using the keyboard shortcut.

```
    "github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable": false
```

I wonder if that's a bug, because there's already multiple ways to disable copilot entirely.

Comment: Exactly, copilot seems no longer to work.

Comment: In case you came here looking for how to turn it off in Visual Studio 2022, there's a sub menu inside Edit which turns it on and off.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In `settings.json` (under File, Preferences, Settings), I found that setting the more general option:

```
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
```

Seems to work as I'd hoped. Copilot suggestions are now only provided on-demand, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, and accepted when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I worry that this might disable other types of suggestions I rely on... but language auto-completion still seems to work. I'll update this answer if I find anything I miss.

**BTW, changing the keyboard shortcuts:**

Under File, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts, if you search for `inlinesuggest`, you see the keystrokes for both triggering inline suggestion and for committing (aka, accepting) inline suggestions. Double-click the row to change the key (but watch out for conflicts.)

[image: VSCode settings for inline suggestions]

Comment: Did you miss other suggestions in the end, or is this solution still working? I am trying out copilot, but like you I cannot take the continuous dumping of BS in my code

Comment: @Imre_G - I still have it off, haven't missed anything.  Sadly, my copilot trial ran out, so I can't comment on the current state of that.

Comment: Well, my company pays for copilot, so I can turn it back on. Sadly, I can't get a nice UX without switching `inlineSuggest` on and off. When it's on, it suggestions show up too often and conflict with intellisense / completion. When it's off, it's hard to trigger and I can't get it to accept (tab doesn't accept copilot suggestions, only intellisense.) I want both, but usually intellisense, and copilot only upon `ALT-\` request

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Asking ChatGPT is way more bang for you buck IMO. Maybe Copilot X will change things..

Comment: While this solution still works, there is a new propper setting (since April 23) that fixes this:
**"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": false**

Comment: see also this thread: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/7323?sort=new

Answer (score 16):

For Jetbrains IDE (e.g. Webstorm).

You can uncheck `automatically show completions` in the IDE's settings (Settings > Languages & Frameworks > GitHub Copilot).
[image]

and then still **TRIGGER** completion with a keystroke `Alt+\` or any keymap you are comfortable with (Settings > Keymap > "Copilot" in the search bar):
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 9):

The top rated solution does not seem to work anymore. However the above solution by @BiasInput also works in VSCode.

Open user settings.json and set `"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": false`
[image]

Then trigger copilot suggestions with the keyboard shorcut you assigned to the command `editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger`.
[image]

Comment: @jeff-ward's solution seems to still work in VS Code for me. Disabled `editor.inlineSuggest.enabled` and I can trigger inline suggestion by keyboard shortcut if desired

Answer (score 4):

## UPDATE 2024

I've made this extension in VS Code, which makes this whole process much easier: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Bubulus.copilot-inline-toggle

#### Old Post

For anyone who just needs to temporarily disable the inline suggestion that overrides intellisense --> a convenient solution that worked for me, was toggling this setting:

```json
"github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions"
```

When **true**, Copilot will work as expected, and give you his inline greyed-out suggestions that can be accepted with tab.

When **false**, Copilot will still work, but the inline suggestions and autocomplete on tab will be disabled. Thus if you are seeking to temporarily only go for intellisense autocompletion, then this does the trick well.

For toggling, I choose the [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler) VS Code extension.

To configure this, you need to add the toggle behavior with a corresponding unique `id` to your settings.json file. For example, I have this config:

```json
 "settings.cycle": [
    {
      "id": "copilotInline",
      "overrideWorkspaceSettings": false,
      "values": [
        {
          "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true
        },
        {
          "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Then to toggle between those two provided values, just add a preferred keybinding to the command by citing the chosen id like this in the keybindings.json file:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+oem_3",
    "command": "settings.cycle.copilotInline"
  }
```

In my case on `ctrl + ö` I toggle between those states now!

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks for taking the time to explain it and make an extension for it. It happens to be exactly what I've been looking for for weeks