# Is there a way to disable automatic inline suggestions from GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

Is it possible to not have GitHub Copilot automatically suggest code, instead only showing its suggestions when using the "trigger inline suggestion" shortcut?

I saw there is a setting `github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable` in Visual Studio Code for this, but can't find any way to do this in Visual Studio.

Comment: Does disabling this extension solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is extremely straightforward. We simply need to

1. Download the [`VSIX` package from `marketplace.visualstudio.com`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilotvs)
2. Extract the `VSIX` contents as a zip archive
3. Decompile the `GitHub.Copilot.Vsix.dll` library into C# using [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
4. Modify `Method:GitHub.Copilot.CopilotOptionPage.SaveSettingsToStorage()` to add the option `InlineSuggest`

   ```csharp
   copilotSettings.InlineSuggest = this.viewModel.InlineSuggest;
   ```
5. Decompile the `copilot-agent-win.exe` vercel/pkg build package from the above folder using the [NSA ghidra tool](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra) and the [NodeJS plugin fork of `ghidra_nodejs`](https://github.com/mavaddat/ghidra_nodejs)
6. Download the [VS Code `VSIX` bundled version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot) of copilot and extract as zip archive.
7. Inspect the JavaScript and identify how the `InlineSuggest` is implemented.
8. Add the `InlineSuggest` option to the JavaScript of the decompiled code mimicking the functionality in the VS Code extension.
9. Re-package the [JavaScript as a vercel/pkg build package](https://blog.sivamuthukumar.com/vercel-pkg-nodejs).
10. Re-package the `VSIX` extension for Visual Studio using [the extension development procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/shipping-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022).
11. Load the double-reverse-engineered extension into Visual Studio.

If you are feeling generous, [share the modified code with Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/faqs-report-an-issue) so they can implement your improvement in their extension. Mind you, the code base is not public, so you may want to [submit the changes anonymously](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/a-beginners-guide-to-tor-how-to-navigate-through-the-underground-internet/).

Answer (score -1):

From what I could find: GitHub Copilot does not have an explicit option to disable automatic code suggestions and only shows them when using the "trigger inline suggestion" shortcut.

Also, it's worth mentioning that Visual Studio Code and GitHub Copilot are separate entities, and they might have different configurations and settings available. Therefore, it is possible that the setting `github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable` is specific to Visual Studio Code and may not be applicable to Visual Studio.

Now, there's a solution, that will satisfy your request, but it's in a different environment app: [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Here's the the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74864825/14701509). Good luck!