How to remove this back highlighted text in Visual Studio Code
Before I write anything in Visual Studio Code, it shows me this like you can see in the given picture. I want to disable this:

I tried out to remove this kind of suggestion but couldn't get solution.

I think that's an extension doing that. Try an extension bisect.

Oh wait, that's Copilot. I've never used it myself.

@wjandrea not necessarily. duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77715724/11107541 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/71224911/11107541
